# Primefaces no está definido - error javaScript

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, glassfish

Buenas,

Estoy usando Primefaces versión 5.3 junto con bootsfaces para mi capa web. El problema que tengo es que me sale el error "Primefaces is not defined" en un facelet donde hago uso del componente **poll** deste esta forma:

```
<b:row id="results">
   <c:if test="${not empty twitterSearch.text or not empty twitterSearch.result }">
       <b:panel  title="Tweets for #{twitterSearch.text}" collapsible="false" look="info" col-md="6">
         <h:form>
            <p:poll interval="3" update="sentimentChart"  />
            <p:chart id="sentimentChart" type="pie" model="#{liveSentimentChartBean.liveCharts.get(twitterSearch.text)}" style="width:400px;height:300px"/>
         </h:form>
       </b:panel>
   </c:if>
</b:row>
```

Este facelet llamado analysis.xhtml es un facelet client de la template app_template.xhtml y por tanto su elemento raíz es el siguiente:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/app_template.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Sé que el problema se suele deber a que falta la etiqueta **head** en el facelet, pero esta está definida en el template de esta forma:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>#{i18n['page.title']}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
        <meta name="DISTRIBUTION" content="GLOBAL" />
        <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <c:set var="root" value="#{request.contextPath}/" />
        <ui:insert name="navbar">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/content/navbar.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
        <b:container>
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </b:container>
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:remove>
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/content/footer.xhtml"/>
            </ui:remove>
        </ui:insert>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

¿Alguien sabe a que puede deberse el problema?
Gracias por adelantado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu archivo análisis pon también

`xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`

o

`< h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="primefaces.js" />`